# ANDROID com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: hyperlink, packet

I have a problem when I try to insert into data in the database. When the activity is opened, the connection is OK, and SELECT is OK, and I receive data and show the data on screen, that is not the problem.

I am sure that connection is no close , because I have no programm it, but I don't know why I cannot INSERT INTO data in the database.

In the screen there is no Error, there are Warnings, that I will copy below. Does anybody why I am not allowed to insert data in a table in the same database?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.X.X:3306/BBDD,user,password);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery(ConsultSQL);
```

INSERT CODE

```
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO data(name, number) VALUES ('" + "hi" + "', " + 3 + ")");
```

ERROR / WARNINGS:

> 01-30 04:21:02.739: W/System.err(2232): com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>       01-30 04:21:02.739: W/System.err(2232): The last packet successfully received from the server was 10.447 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
>       01-30 04:21:02.739: W/System.err(2232):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>       01-30 04:21:02.739: W/System.err(2232):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>       01-30 04:21:02.739: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       01-30 04:21:02.739: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
>       01-30 04:21:02.739: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4165)
>       01-30 04:21:02.739: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
>       01-30 04:21:02.739: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
>       01-30 04:21:02.749: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2819)
>       01-30 04:21:02.749: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
>       01-30 04:21:02.749: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
>       01-30 04:21:02.749: D/audio_hw_primary(86): start_output_stream: card:0, port:0, rate:44100
>       01-30 04:21:02.749: W/System.err(2232):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
>       01-30 04:21:02.759: W/System.err(2232):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       01-30 04:21:02.759: W/System.err(2232):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       01-30 04:21:02.759: W/System.err(2232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>       01-30 04:21:02.759: W/System.err(2232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       01-30 04:21:02.759: W/System.err(2232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       01-30 04:21:02.769: W/System.err(2232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>       01-30 04:21:02.769: W/System.err(2232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>       01-30 04:21:02.769: W/System.err(2232):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       01-30 04:21:02.769: W/System.err(2232): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>       01-30 04:21:02.769: W/System.err(2232):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
>       01-30 04:21:02.769: W/System.err(2232):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
>       01-30 04:21:02.769: W/System.err(2232):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:503)
>       01-30 04:21:02.769: W/System.err(2232):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
>       01-30 04:21:02.769: W/System.err(2232):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
>       01-30 04:21:02.769: W/System.err(2232):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
>       01-30 04:21:02.769: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
>       01-30 04:21:02.769: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
>       01-30 04:21:02.779: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
>       01-30 04:21:02.779: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3163)
>       01-30 04:21:02.779: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3620)
>       01-30 04:21:02.779: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
>       01-30 04:21:02.779: W/System.err(2232):     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4160)
>       01-30 04:21:02.779: W/System.err(2232):     ... 16 more

Comment: Is there the MysqlConnector.jar file in your system ?

Comment: Re write the line with conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.X.X:3306/BBDD","user","password");